# How to get the count of all existant CKeditor's instances in a webApplication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor5

I've seen that the "free" version of `CKeditor 5` is limited to '5 active users' : [CKeditor pricing plans](https://ckeditor.com/pricing/);

is there a way to know how many instances are there in all my application ?

Answer (score 1):

You may get the count like that:

```
var instanceCount = 0;
for(var instances in CKEDITOR.instances){
   instanceCount++;
}
```

Comment: I've mentionned "CKeditor 5" , using your answer i get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined` , I think your solution is only available with previous versions of CKeditor, thanks you anyway.

Comment: Check this out https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#what-happened-to-the-global-windowckeditor-how-to-list-all-instances-of-the-editor